# Show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_2}}$ for three mutually tangent circles, each tangent to a common line

Tags: geometry, circles, radicals, fractions, tangent-line

> Three circles are tangents to the line $AB$. Being $r_1$ the radius of the biggest one, $r_2$ the radius of the middle one and $r_3$ the radius of the smallest. Show that $$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r_3}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r_1}}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{r_2}}.$$

Hint:show that $AB = 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}$.

[image: 3 tangent circles tangent to line]

I know I have to use the Pitagora`s Theorem.

Comment: You might find the generalization of this problem interesting. It is a result called [Descartes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_theorem). Given three circles with curvatures $k_i=1/r_i$, there are two other circles that are tangent to all three (one externally tangent, one internally tangent). Their curvatures are given by: $k_1+k_2+k_3\pm\sqrt{k_1k_2+k_2k_3+k_3k_1}$. In this case, line $\overline{AB}$ can be treated as a circle with $0$ curvature, and Descartes' formula will simplify to the formula in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be tangency points to the biggest circle and to the middle circle respectively.

Also, let $O_1$, $O_2$ and $O_3$ be centers of circles with radius $r_1$, $r_2$ and $r_3$ respectively

and let $O_3K$ and $O_3M$ be perpendiculars from $O_3$ to $O_1A$ and $O_2B$ respectively.

Thus, $O_1K=r_1-r_3$, $O_1O_3=r_1+r_3$ and by the Pythagoras's theorem we obtain:
$$O_3K=\sqrt{(r_1+r_3)^2-(r_1+r_3)^2}=2\sqrt{r_1r_3}.$$
Similarly $$O_3M=2\sqrt{r_2r_3}$$ and
$$AB=2\sqrt{r_1r_2}$$ and since $AB=O_3K+O_3M$, we obtain:
$$2\sqrt{r_1r_2}=2\sqrt{r_1r_3}+2\sqrt{r_2r_3}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_3}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_2}}.$$
Done!

Answer (score 0):

Let $C$ be the tangency point of the middle circle. If you could show that $AB = 2\sqrt{r_1r_3},$ then similarly you can show that $AC = 2\sqrt{r_1r_2}$ and $CB = 2\sqrt{r_2r_3}$ and use the fact that $AB = AC+CB.$ Your result will follow immediately.

As for how to prove the hint, look at the trapezoid $ABSL$, where $S$ and $L$ are the centers of the smaller and the larger circles respectively.

Comment: Why is $AB\neq2r_1+2r_2$?